# My client is asking for more "wow factor."

Tags: design, graphic-design, graphics

I have heard since the beginning of this project that the product I am redesigning lacks the "wow factor." I assume that in this context, the wow factor ("properties belonging to an object that pleasantly surprise") means barrier-free usability, easy navigation, concealment of complexity (and its progressive revelation), and overall a pleasant user experience.

I have heard only one thing about the client's taste: they love Apple. There are three possible conclusions that may be drawn from this remark:

1) they have iPhones and iPads and love iOS, (this is true)
2) they have Macs and love OS X (this is also true), or
3) they love the UX provided by the online Apple store.

To my surprise, the answer that finally emerged was that they love the online Apple store's UX. I thought that this was surely the least likely meaning of "they love Apple."

I have completed the initial redesign. It fulfills all the functional requirements in an elegant, self-explanatory, and restrained manner. This is the way I design: almost flat, justifying each pixel (see Ben Hunt) and using the smallest effective difference. I said this in my initial presentation: "Every pixel must perform, inform, or guide. All others are decorative. (after Ben Hunt)."

I am now being asked to decorate my nearly minimalist, almost flat, clean and uncluttered design to satisfy the customer's repeated request for the "wow factor," a requirement that no one can define. I am in a difficult position, given that I am prototyping in Axure and there seems to be no way to do wow-y things in the environment (I could, of course, graft some script, code, and visual resources on the prototype, but anyone who has tried to do that knows how much of a pain in the neck it is).

I have suggested that the most likely candidate for decorative graphics is the client's own website, with marketing language attached. But that implies a CMS module to manage the graphics and text (even if they don't know it now, they will be asking for this within 30 days).

Please help me think this through. How do I transform a simple, nearly minimalist, almost flat, clean, and uncluttered design by incorporating the ever-mysterious wow factor to create something bouncy, flashy, fun, and I dunno, "WOW!"

DKR

Comment: You obviously have different design priorities than your client; instead of asking us to figure out what "WOW" is, why not hash it out with your client?

Answer (score 6):

Phrases like...

- add some wow!
- make it pop!
- needs more pizazz!

...mean absolutely nothing other than the client is looking at something that doesn't meet their expectations that are in their mind.

It also typically comes from clients that are treating their web pages as pieces of art they'd hang up in a dining room rather than as usable tools that their customers will interact with to give them money.

The challenge for you is to redirect the client's concerns so that they focus on their customer's experience first and foremost.

So, I think you are on the right track. If you are in a check-out process, for example, that's not the place for decoration. That's the place for making the process as absolutely easy as possible to ensure people complete the transaction.

Another technique is to ask them for examples of what they like. Odds are if they come back with lots of highly decorated UIs, you'll likely find that your hunch is correct--and that most of them will be marketing-level pages rather than shopping-level pages.

Bottom line, you need to get the client interacting with you on a deeper level beyond 'add some wow' as that isn't a phrase that really helps either you nor the client move forward.